How does Tsongkhapa understand the "insight" into emptiness?
Tsongkhapa and the Gelug school in general place great emphasis on the analysis of the emptiness of each thing. However, after this analysis, they also insist on having an "insight" into this object. It is, so to speak, like seeing "floaters" in my eyes and my doctor telling me that it is an ocular problem, not actual flies. I still have the experience of seeing flies, but I know that the object of this perception is an ocular condition. If I undergo surgery, this object is also confirmed subjectively, phenomenologically, and my experience aligns with the object. Something similar happens with the method Tsongkhapa proposes.
What I want to know is: what kind of act does Tsongkhapa understand this to be? Is it a non-conceptual perception? Is it an intuition?

As long as the phenomena needs to be analyzed it is insight meditation using concepts of illusion or dreams etc. When we have direct experience of emptiness without any analysis then it is non-conceptual experience. It is a direct experience of emptiness. Repeated analysis or insight meditation along with concentrated mind gives us direct experience of emptiness. Ultimately you should aim for direct experience of emptiness which is non-conceptual.
This method is called analytical meditation or special insight.

Thank you. I have two questions: Tsongkhapa says that repeated analysis + concentration gives access to the experience of emptiness? And secondly: what kind of act does Tsongkhapa understand this experience to be? Direct non-conceptual perception? What would be the Tibetan word?  In the "Great Treatise" He talks about this (cf. ch. 26-27) but I can't find the text in Tibetan.

@Ian I am not an expert in Tibetan Buddhism. But I can tell you that direct perception of emptiness is a first order experience. It is not a result of reflective consciousness.

@Ian is that Tibetan word sems tsam?

@blue_eggo I think this is more of a Cittamatra concept, isn't it?
